# WAS Liberty adminCenter login displays login.css page

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have configured my Websphere Liberty server to support the Admin Center as described in the IBM Knowledge center.

I am running WAS Liberty version 17.0.0.1 on Windows 10 from an eclipse Neon environment (ie. on localhost).  I connect with the URL (http://localhost:9080/adminCenter) from Chrome (version 61).

It puts up a login page (not great looking but serviceable)

[image: Admin Center login page]

I enter my credentials and click Submit and I am taken to the login.css webpage.

Within the Chrome developer tools, I can see an error message on the console indicating the GET for favicon.ico failed.

Then I can go to the browser address bar, manually change the URL to point to the adminCenter  and it takes me to the Toolbox page for the Admin Center.  From there I can select the Server Config graphic and see my server data.

Can anyone identify what I have configured wrong that is causing the AdminCenter to display the login.css webpage rather than re-route to the adminCenter webpage after I login?

Additionally, if anyone can direct me to instructions on how to put up a more user-friendly login page, I would be very grateful.  (I'm doing my client-side application development in Angular.  The only information I've found so far for customizing a login page with WAS Liberty references creating a login jsp page which I don't know how to do. (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to provide the URL for this)  I'm still learning Angular and client-side development.)

Comment: I apologize in advance.  I tried to provide links to the resources I've been using but I don't have enough reputation points to include them.

Comment: You should see nice login page to AdminCenter. I suggest you first to try it with different browser e.g. FireFox, as it looks like Chrome is doing request in multiple threads concurrently which breaks the login page.

Comment: I get the same login webpage when I try to access the adminCenter from Firefox.

Comment: Since the browser is complaining that it can't find the favicon, can you check your server's messages.log to see if you're getting an error like "SRVE0190E: File not found: /login/images/favicon.ico".

Comment: You can also try and stop the server and then start it again with the --clean flag to clear any caches on the server.

Comment: I rebooted my system to clear the cache.  (I'm a newbie and only know how to start the server within eclipse.)  When I accessed the AdminCenter and logged in, it took me to this URL:  https://localhost:9443/adminCenter/login/images/IBM_logo_white.png.  I checked the messages.log file and the only error I found was about my certificate being expired.  The other messages indicated the Admin center toolbox and catalog were loaded.

Comment: The server's cache is persisted to disk so it will survive the reboot; in eclipse's Servers view, when you right click on your Liberty server, one of the options should be something like "Clean..." which will allow you to clean the server on the next restart (or go to your wlp/bin dir and run "server stop {serverName}" and then "server start {serverName} --clean".  This won't hurt anything as it's just a cache so it will get rebuilt.  If the problem persists, I would try to re-install the feature in case the archive (jar) somehow got corrupted on download.

Comment: wlp/bin/server stop {yourServerName}
wlp/bin/installUtility uninstall adminCenter-1.0
wlp/bin/installUtility install adminCenter-1.0
wlp/bin/server start {yourServerName} --clean
The above will remove the jars for Admin Center and download them again from the repo.

Comment: I did the clean of the server from the eclipse UI.  Then I ran the uninstall and re-install of the adminCenter-1.0 feature.  All of the messages indicated it was a successful install.  Unfortunately I didn't see any change in behavior.  I still get the IBM_logo-white.png page after authenticating to the admin center.

Comment: What's the error code you're seeing in the browser's network tab for the failing resources?  For some reason (perhaps a firewall/plugin) your browsers are not getting certain, and this includes the css (might be the result of the first file not coming back), which is why you're seeing a login without any styling. If the network tab doesn't lead any clues, you'd probably need to enable server side trace to see if the requests are ever making it to the server, and if so, if the server responds with the file.  This would tell you if it's the server, browser, or something in between (ex. firewall)

Comment: Alternatively, you could try and move up to a newer version of Liberty to see if the problem persists.

Comment: When I access the admin center login page, the console shows two instances of the same error message: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' against login.jsp:4.  When I click on the Sources tab, I see that there are two entries for login.jsp.  The first one is empty and the second one starts with 3 blanks lines and the <!DOCTYPE html> tag is on line 4.  Now when I login today, I am taken to the login.css webpage.  The Network tab shows 3 entries.  1: j_secutiry_check status 302, 2: login.css status 200 and 3: (in red) favicon.ico status 404.  It is looking in /localhost:9443/favicon.ico.

Comment: I finally got the AdminCenter to come up with the appropriate css and logon pages.  I had to remove the custom Trust Association Interceptor that I had configured in my server.xml.  I can successfully logon now, but I am getting this error in the server console CWPKI0022E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN CN=localhost, OU=zSS, O=ibm, C=us was sent from the target host.  The signer might need to be added to local trust store.  I will pursue a solution to this separately from this issue.

Comment: I have done some work to clean up my custom Trust Association Interceptor (TAI) and ensure it is only intercepting the requests which I need to authenticate.  As an additional test, I set up the TAI to always return false from the IsTargetInterceptor method, which effectively means that my TAI never handles any of the requests.  With this configuration, I still get the unstyled login page for the AdminCenter and the redirect after login is to the css pages.  The only time the AdminCenter works properly is when I completely remove my TAI from the WAS Liberty server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you previously accessed a different version of Liberty and accessed its Admin Center on that browser?  If so, your browser (or something else in the network pipe) could be caching old files causing such issues.  When something like that happens, easiest way to check would be to try and open the page (the url you're using is correct, and it correctly redirects you to HTTPS) in a private/incognito tab/window of the browser (ctrl+shift+n for most browsers), or a different browser.  Alternatively, you can clear the cache of the browser you're using for that page/domain (which would also be the actual fix if the cache is indeed the problem.)

Comment: This is the first time I have tried accessing the adminCenter for any WAS Liberty server.  I have only tried on my localhost system where I only have WAS Liberty 17.0.0.1 installed.